# MSI Ubuntu 18.04 (Pop!_OS) stuck airplane mode after suspend

Tags: ubuntu, wifi, suspend, hibernate

my laptop is MSI P65 Creator 9SF (i9-9880H, RTX2070 Max-Q).

OS: Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS x86_64
Host: P65 Creator 9SF REV:1.0
Kernel: 5.3.0-7625-generic

I've already tried editing [grub configuration](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043547/wifi-hard-blocked-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-on-gs65) and [reseting network adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/54710/how-do-i-reset-the-network-adapter-using-a-terminal-command).

Can you give me any advice how can I make it to the point, when I can just close the lid, put laptop into backpack and just open it after some time and have wi-fi working? Would really appreciate.